# Updating the whole prototype chain in Angularjs directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm applying my directive (attribute) to 2 of my modals that are on the same file.
my directive :

```
.directive('myModal', function() {
    return {
        scope : true,
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attr) {
                console.log(scope.dismiss);
                scope.modalElements.push(element);
                scope.dismiss = function(){
                    angular.forEach(modalElements,function(element,key){
                        console.log(element);
                        // element.modal('hide');
                    });
                };
                console.log(scope.dismiss);
                $(element).bind('shown.bs.modal', function () {
                    if (!scope.$root.$$phase){
                        scope.$apply();
                        console.log(scope.dismiss); // the function I want
                        console.log(scope.$parent.dismiss); // the function with alert
                    }
                    });
            }
        };
});
```

and I have this scope at my controller (so it means the child scope of rootscope which is also the parent of parent of parent of the scope created inside the directive).

```
$scope.dismiss = function() {alert(1);};
```

As you can see in my directive, I'm updating the function dismiss.
It works for the current level of scope but it doesn't update the parent scope or the prototyping hierarchy.

Why is that hapening ? should I go through `scope.$parent.$parent.$parent` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you've exhaustively demonstrated in the example how prototype chain works. The inheritance works only in one direction. To overcome this behaviour of prototype inheritance you should define objects on the scope, not functions. E.g.

```
scope.obj = {};
scope.obj.dismiss = function() { ... };
```

This way `scope.obj.dismiss` will be the same in both child and parent scopes, unless `scope.obj` is re-assigned.

Using functions or data from parent controllers in directives either this way or with `scope.$parent` isn't a good practice in general. Directive's `require`, services and `$broadcast`/`$emit` are more appropriate ways of interoperation within Angular.

Comment: The way I was doing it was like the 'premitive' pitfall ?

Comment: Yes. It isn't really related to Angular but to JS prototypal inheritance, but Angular scopes are the place where it becomes prominent. I find Angular's [explaination](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes) a bit too heavy, but It was also covered on SO for [numerous times](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=angular%20scope%20prototyp*%20inheritance).